# When did the change from "die" to "dee" occur?

Tags: history-of-gaming, dice, pronunciation

When speaking about dice, some older gamers will say "die-6", compared to the more common (and seemingly younger) pronunciation of "dee-6".

The only real points of reference I have for this are that my dad, who played AD&D in college, says "die-6", where I go with "dee-6". Additionally, I recall this coming up on Critical Role, with Joe Manganiello telling chat to stop correcting his "die-6" pronunciation, and calling attention to the fact that it's just an older way of referring to dice.

Obviously, the change occurred some time between AD&D and 5e, but that's a fairly broad period of time! I want to know if anyone remembers when the change happened to move *away* from saying "die-6". [This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176163/dee-twenty-and-die-twenty-pronunciations) has a wonderful answer explaining where that pronunciation *arose*, but not when it fell out of fashion.

Comment: “Does anyone know when and where this nomenclature arose?”—sounds like that question certainly does ask “when,” and the top answer definitely suggests a time frame. I’m not seeing enough distinction in this question to warrant it being kept separate, myself. It seems very unlikely that anyone is going to do better than Quadratic Wizard in answering it, too.

Comment: @KRyan I was hoping someone who had been active throughout that time might have more personal experience. I linked that question myself, because it's very clearly related, but it doesn't really satisfy my question of when die- pronunciation fell out of fashion. It explains when it started, not when it ended.

Comment: [(Almost) the same question at board and card games SE](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/53510/34651), also answered by Quadratic Wizard.

Comment: The top answer also makes it pretty clear that “die” was not universally used _ever_, so for most people it _never_ “changed,” “dee” was the only pronunciation that was ever used. Considering that at least one person on Critical Role _still_ uses “die,” it’s not clear (at all) to me what you’re actually asking after—per QW’s answer, it was used by a minority of gamers since roughly the early ’80s, and that minority has been dwindling ever since but nonetheless remains extant.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Also doesn't have an explanation for *when* the useage fell out of fashion. I suppose that it could be inferred that as the community became more unified, the nomenclature standardized, but I'd rather not speculate baselessly.

Comment: Verily, Sir Manganiello,  I say unto thee that such verbiage is most out of date, sir.

Comment: @TigerGuy Indubitably.